# pipe email hosted at Amazon SES with aws workmail to ec2 hosted php script

Tags: php, mysql, email, amazon-ses, amazon-workmail

I have a website hosted on an amazon ec2 and I have the websites email address hosted at amazon SES, we also use amazon workmail to access the emails and send out emails. However now what we would like to do is pipe all email sent to our websites email address into a php mysql script (we are building a communication management system).

However I can not find any suggestions or documentation on how I would be able to forward emails received into the aws workmail inbox to an external hosted php file?

Comment: I am unclear on how I would be able to get the raw email from Amazon S3? Does anyone know of a decent tutorial or code samples of how to get the actual raw email from s3 via php (maybe curl)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Second answer because I didn't read the question properly (whoops, sorry).

Email attachments are sent as part of the message body using [MIME encoding](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2045). When receiving emails from SES, you'll get them in this raw format as part of the message body.

However, SES will limit the message size (including attachments) to 150kb when sending to SNS.

To support larger messages (30MB) you'll want to store these in S3. To receive an SNS event when a new message has arrived, you'll want to set up an [S3 Event Notification](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html) for `s3:ObjectCreated:*`.

From there, the process is the same - your application will need to retrieve the object from S3, and extract the messages and attachments from the body of the object, optionally deleting the original message from S3 when you're done.

The only decent looking PHP library for extracting attachments is [php-mime-mail-parser](https://github.com/php-mime-mail-parser/php-mime-mail-parser) and there's a decent example on their GitHub page.

I've adapted the example to show the relevant pieces:

```
$Parser = new PhpMimeMailParser\Parser();
$Parser->setText($raw_email);

foreach ($Parser->getAttachments(true) as $attachment) {
    echo 'Filename : '.$attachment->getFilename().'<br />'; // logo.jpg
    echo 'Filesize : '.filesize($attach_dir.$attachment->getFilename()).'<br />'; // 1000
    echo 'Filetype : '.$attachment->getContentType().'<br />'; // image/jpeg
    echo 'MIME part string : '.$attachment->getMimePartStr().'<br />'; // (the whole MIME part of the attachment)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The service you're looking for is AWS Simple Email Service (SES). AWS added support for inbound email handling in 2015.

[Documentation here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/receiving-email.html)

To get started you will need to configure & verify your domain in SES and point the domains DNS `MX` record to SES as directed in the console.

From there, you can create rules based on the destination address to send messages on of: Lambda Function; S3; SNS; or Workmail.

For your case of processing on EC2, you'd want to publish messages to an SNS topic, with a subscribed SQS queue. Your application server on EC2 would then need to consume messages from the SQS in a worker thread.

It is possible to use this to handle all messages on the domain you have WorkMail on, however unless your specific product requires it - I'd recommend setting up a subdomain specifically for email addresses to be handled by automation.

Comment: If you really really don't want to set up the consumer, you can register a Lambda action and write a lambda function to convert mail messages for submission to your HTTP interface. However this isn't as fault tolerant (out of the box) as the queuing approach.

Comment: I should also note that if you're automating your infrastructure, SES isn't currently supported by CloudFormation... I really hope they address this in the future.

Comment: What I am not sure of is how to compose the SNS action so that it sends the message with any attachments to the EC2 endpoint